# Как получить данные из таблицы с помощью XPATH

Tags: xpath

Хочу получить список прокси с сайта https://www.ip-adress.com/proxy-list, но не могу получить одновременно IP и порт. Как мне построить XPATH запрос так, чтобы я получил данные как на картинке ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При таком запросе я поучаю всю ноду, а мне нужен только текст/

Если делаю такой запрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То только порты. href выпадают. Как мне получить и href и текст одновременно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вот этот запрос: `//tr/td[1]` возвращает целиком узел, содержащий именно то, что вам нужно. Обычно можно получить текст всего этого узла (включая все дочерние узлы) уровнем выше. Например, если XPath-запрос вызывается из языка типа C#, там можно получить весь текст из свойства наподобие `node.InnerText`.
2. Попробуйте следующий запрос:

   ```
   //tr/td[1]/descendant-or-self::*/text()
   ```